# What are the consequences of revealing pattern in prime numbers?

Tags: prime-numbers

I have been studying structure of numbers and came across a unique property of prime numbers. I would be happy to share my discovery, which would help, for example, in understanding Goldbach's conjecture. On the other hand the pattern I see could be used in order to break RSA encryption, which puts issue on security of financial transactions on the Internet.

Is there any way I can present this knowledge to be safe and contribution at the same time?

Comment: Probably, you just think you discovered something. Just put it online and someone will point out why it doesn't work.

Comment: What I mean is it could be anyone who found the pattern. Perhaps there is more people who have got 'something', but care about other concerns.

Answer (score 3):

If (and I regard that as highly unlikely) you have discovered a pattern that is actually worth anything:publish it. Others might have discovered it and chosen to keep it to them self, and use it to snoop on other people's encrypted stuff, meaning that nobody is really safe anyway.

And the only way to find out if your pattern is worth anything is to publish it, so in short: publish it.

Comment: It doesn't solve the balance I have issue with ...

Answer (score 0):

**If** you would have such a pattern, it could break RSA encryption. However, I'm pretty sure your pattern isn't what you think it is. If you could post it, we can tell you where your flaw is.

Comment: How can you be sure of something you haven't seen yet?

Comment: Statistically, I can say that you are one of the many people that think that has found such a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would clarify that I believe as well that your pattern isn't what you think it is. Furthermore, I would vote for close this topic as it is not about math as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and because it is mainly opinion-based.

Apart from this, I imagine you do not want to share your pattern here or anywhere, because you are concerned with "security". In this case, there exists the concept of "zero-knowledge proof". You may have a look and see if this fits your needs. You may discover by yourself that your patter doesn't work as you imagine.

Comment: Believe is not enough, we must know.